# C# UDP packet sniffer stack to datatable and bind to datagrid

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagrid, udpclient

I am trying to construct a listener to UDP packets in c# using the snippet on the microsoft webpage. When the packets arrive, they come in groups and I am trying to add them to a datatable then plan to create a few more variables within the datatable from the inserted data.

The problem occurs when I create the datatable and add the data (last line in example below), the datatable has reverted back to null and i can't insert the data - how do i do this? And finally how do i bind to a datagrid to display the datatable?

Many thanks,

```
            //Creates a UdpClient for reading incoming data.
            UdpClient receivingUdpClient = new UdpClient(int.Parse(txtPort.Text));

            //Creates an IPEndPoint to record the IP Address and port number of the sender.
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            try
            {
                // Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host.
                Byte[] receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
                string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

                // Parse message
                var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(message);

                // Iterate
                Iteration += 1;

                // On first ever iteration, set first timestamp
                if (FirstIteration == true)
                {
                    FirstTimestamp = item.A;
                    Date = item.B;
                    Time = item.C;
                    FirstIteration = false;

                    //create new empty datatable
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Columns.Add("Date");
                    dt.Columns.Add("Time");
                    dt.Rows.Add(Date, Time);
                }

                // On first group iteration, set first timestamp
                if (Iteration == 1)
                {
                    MinTimestamp = item.T;
                }

                // Start Stacking data
                if (MinTimestamp == item.T & Iteration <= Max)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(Date, Time);
                }
```

Comment: Where is your loop to receive more than one message?  You only need to create one connection to receive data and one datatable.

Comment: It is a simplified version - my issue is that it throws an exception on the last line "dt is null"- but how can it be null when i've just created it?

Comment: So, i create the datatable, add columns and add a row. Then for testing purposes i add another row (at the bottom of the script) and this is where it throws an exception: "dt is null"

Comment: You r code can't work!!!  You must have dt defined twice in the code.  The following is inside the if statement : DataTable dt = new DataTable();  So the datatable is not defined at bottom of code.

Comment: But i only want to define it once as i want to add to it on each iteration? So i've defined it on the first iteration?

Comment: The code gives compiler errors.  You want to define the table in a common part of the code but call the constructor once. So at top of module use DataTable dt = null.